# SQL query to to add three more rows in a single query

Tags: sql

I have a question about a SQL query, the following is the table I am using:

Table name: **sample**

```
id|value|name|age  
 1|   3 |hari|23
```

I have 3 more values 8,9,12 the id is auto incrementing, the name `age` is same. Only value is changing in 3 cases.

I need to write a single sql query to accomplish the result.

The output should be,

```
id|value|name|age  
 1|   3 |hari|23    
 2|   8 |hari|23  
 3|   9 |hari|23  
 4|  12 |hari|23
```

Comment: Where do those extra values come from? Your question isn't very clear....

Answer (score 3):

You can use a extended insert to accomplish your task.

```
INSERT INTO samples (value, name, age) 
VALUES (8, 'hari', 23), 
       (9, 'hari', 23),
       (12, 'hari', 23);
```

Comment: @DevZer0..If it is only 3 value means it is ok..there may be 5 or more..these are dynamically coming..I need to add to the database dynamically

Comment: you can generate the syntax with the language your using.

Comment: the above query works only with the SQL Server database with versions 2008 or above. It is called insert using "Table Value Constructor".

Answer (score 0):

In SQL use this format

```
   INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
   ( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

or you can go with

```
      INSERT INTO table(column1, column2,column3 ) 
      SELECT value 1, value 2 , value 3
      UNION ALL
      SELECT value 1,value 2, value 3
```

Comment: This *might* work on some systems - but it's by no means supported by **all** SQL-based databases.....